# XML serialize step up every second row

Tags: vb.net

ia m trying to serialize xml file and i am facing some issue. Look below at my xml sample file:

```
<Information xmlns="dis">
    <SOS.Alert>
    <signal>4</signal>
    <tresh>RTX</tresh>
    <obb>GGHUI</obb>
    </SOS.Alert>
    <SOS.Alert>
    <signal>3</signal>
    <tresh>RTR</tresh>
    <obb>GGH</obb>
    </SOS.Alert>
    <SOS.Alert>
    <signal>20</signal>
    <tresh>WWRTX</tresh>
    <obb>BBHUI</obb>
    </SOS.Alert>
    <SOS.Alert>
    <signal>13</signal>
    <tresh>DRTR</tresh>
    <obb>GFH</obb>
    </SOS.Alert>
    ....
</Information>
```

the problem is it's skipping every "second". So if we we have 4 inputs like above only two will be serialized:

```
<SOS.Alert>
<signal>4</signal>
<tresh>RTX</tresh>
<obb>GGHUI</obb>
</SOS.Alert>
<SOS.Alert>
<signal>20</signal>
<tresh>WWRTX</tresh>
<obb>BBHUI</obb>
</SOS.Alert>
```

This is the code i am using:

```
Me.xmlreader = New XmlTextReader(inputFileName)


            Me.xmlreader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None
            While (Me.xmlreader.Read())
                If ((Me.xmlreader.Name = "SOS.Alert") And (Me.xmlreader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element) And (Me.xmlreader.IsStartElement())) Then

                    Me.data.MyList.Add(xmlreader.ReadOuterXml)
                End If

            End While
```

Comment: Is there a root node? Otherwise this seems not to be valid XML doc

Comment: yes it has see updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**((Me.xmlreader.Name = "SOS.Alert")** should be **((Me.xmlreader.LocalName = "SOS.Alert")**

- .**Name** has the Namespace included: dis:SOS.Alert
- .**LocalName** has the prefix removed: SOS.ALert

Other approach

```
Imports <xmlns:dis="dis"> ' required for example 2
```

.
.
.

```
Dim _xmlString As String = <Information xmlns="dis">
                                  <SOS.Alert>
                                        <signal>4</signal>
                                        <tresh>RTX</tresh>
                                        <obb>GGHUI</obb>
                                  </SOS.Alert>
                                  <SOS.Alert>
                                        <signal>3</signal>
                                        <tresh>RTR</tresh>
                                        <obb>GGH</obb>
                                  </SOS.Alert>
                                  <SOS.Alert>
                                        <signal>20</signal>
                                        <tresh>WWRTX</tresh>
                                        <obb>BBHUI</obb>
                                  </SOS.Alert>
                                  <SOS.Alert>
                                        <signal>13</signal>
                                        <tresh>DRTR</tresh>
                                        <obb>GFH</obb>
                                  </SOS.Alert>
                             </Information>.ToString

Dim _xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(_xmlString)

' Example 1
For Each _x As XElement In From _e In _xdoc.Root.Descendants Where _e.Name.LocalName = "SOS.Alert" Select _e
    Debug.WriteLine(_x.ToString)
Next

' Example 2 - requires "Imports <xmlns:dis="dis">" the namespace of the xml
Dim _xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(_xmlString)
For Each _x As XElement In _xdoc.Root.<dis:SOS.Alert>
    Debug.WriteLine(_x.ToString)
Next
```

Comment: i will test it asap. Whats diffrence betwen Name and localName and why this way?

Comment: Updated my answer, it is about the Namespace

Comment: You can load a xml doc with _xdoc = XDcocument.Load(_file_) or you really need a xmltextreader?

Comment: i cant use your solution anyway because the xml file contains more than 1,5 gb i am receiving outofmemoryexception during Parse method, any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: LocalName instead Local do same.